# Stochastic model of a RL circuit

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, numerical-methods, mathematical-modeling, stochastic-differential-equations

I would like to solve stochastic electric circuits numerically. I already know that I should use Milstein method to solve those systems. However, I'm not sure if the stochastic differential equations are correct, if the modeling is correct. Thus, could you give me a feedback whether or not my reasoning is correct?

Consider a [series RL circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RL_circuit#/media/File:Series-RL.png) . Mathematically, it can be modeled as:

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\dot{I}(t) = \frac{V_L(t)}{L} \\
\dot{V_L}(t) = \dot{V}(t) - R \dot{I}(t)
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

As previously stated, I want it to be a stochastic electric circuit. Thus, all parameters should be random variables. For example, I want them to satisfy:

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
L = L_0 + e^{B_t} \\
R = R_0 + e^{B_t} \\
V(t) = V_0 \sin(120 \pi t) + \sigma B_t
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

where $B_t$ stands for brownian motion and the other constants are all real positive ones.

With that in mind,

1. Rewrite both equations in differential form:

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
dI = \frac{V_L(t)}{L}dt \\
dV_L = dV - R dI
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

2. Substitute the parameters:

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
dI = \frac{V_L(t)}{L_0 + e^{B_t}}dt \\
dV_L = 120 \pi V_0 \cos( 120 \pi t) dt + \sigma dB_t - \underbrace{(R_0 + e^{B_t}) dI}_{?}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

The part "?" feels weird to me. Because I'm used to solve such kind of systems numerically:

\begin{equation}
d \vec{X} = \vec{F}(t, \vec{X}) dt + \vec{G}(t, \vec{X}) d\vec{W}
\end{equation}

Surely, I could use substitution. Thus I would arrive at the last kind of equation for one dimension. But I would like to solve systems of SDEs numerically.

Is this reasoning correct? Personally, I do think it is. But this field is quite new to me and sometimes tricky.

Thanks

P.S.: I have just read [this book on stochastic calculus](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/3856#t=aboutBook). I'm an electrical engineering student.

**EDIT**

The original problem is: I would like to solve stochastic electrical circuits numerically. That means I have the following things to do:

1. model the electrical circuit using stochastic differential equations. Which I'm yet not sure if the reasoning is correct;
2. find the equations that can entirely describe the dynamics of the circuit;
3. set up the following equation:

\begin{equation}
d \vec{X} = \vec{F}(t, \vec{X}) dt + \vec{G}(t, \vec{X}) d\vec{W}
\end{equation}

4. use Milstein's method to solve it numerically.

An attempt to answer question 1 has been done right above. There I try to model a series RL circuit.

The answers to question 2 and 3 depends whether or not my attempt to answer question 1 is correct or not. That's why this question focuses on the validity of the stochastic model and its reasoning.

Finally, question 4 is already solved. I know how to implement Milstein's method numerically.

Comment: Google spits out this paper which might be useful as a point of comparison: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1630179

Comment: @Semiclassical thanks for your comment! Yes, I have already read this paper. The author derives it in a different way and does not consider: 1) L to be a random variable and 2) the system of equations. In other words, it's a one dimensional problem, which is not what I would like to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You can uncouple the two SDEs by substituting the first equation into the second one, sucht that
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathrm{d}V_L 
   &=&\displaystyle
   \mathrm{d}V - R\mathrm{d}I = \mathrm{d}V - \frac{R}{L}V_L\mathrm{d}t \\
   &=&\displaystyle
   \left(120\pi V_0\cos(120\pi t) + \frac{R_0+e^{B_t}}{L_0+e^{B_t}}V_L\right)\mathrm{d}t + \sigma\mathrm{d}B_t
\end{array}
$$
which is a one-dimensional SDE with the standard structure (that you can solve numerically). Once you get it, the other variable is given by
$$
I(t) = I(t_0) + \int_{t_0}^t \frac{V_L(s)}{L_0+e^{B_s}} \mathrm{d}s
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I also thought I could do it. But this coupled system was just an example of what I truly must solve, which is a system of many many more equations. Although it's a very good trick, it would be unfeasible for me.

Comment: @Mr.N  You should tell us about your original problem, in order to avoid an "XY problem". Perhaps there's a similar trick or manipulation, because systems of equations are solved by successive substitutions in the end.

Comment: Ok. Sure. Let me edit the question.